# C++ Server, System.10014 error, using Boost

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

**Update: I figured it out! Kind of... I'm not sure how this fixed it, but it did. Instead of using:**

```
NetworkMessage msg;
msg.AddByte(0x01);
sendmessage(msg);
```

**I tried this and it worked(with few changes to some functions)**

```
NetworkMessage* msg = new NetworkMessage();
msg.AddByte(0x01);
sendmessage(msg);
```

**This fixed it, but would still appreciate an explanation from anyone of why this was happening in the first place. Post it as an answer so I can mark it. Thank you.**

I've been working on a TCP Server but I've been having a little problem..

There's a loop that sends about 600? messages, sending 1 at a time(reading from queued message list).

For some reason, about 200 reach my client without errors, then I get a System.10014 error. Every time on a different message, even though the messages are the same every time. Also, if I just re-send the message after System.10014 error, it works fine. So it's obvious the message is not the problem. But I have no idea what is. I've spend the entire day yesterday trying to figure it out and still no luck. So here I am. Again.

```
void outputMessage(NetworkMessage& msg, bool forceTrue = false)
{
    if(!connectionLocked || forceTrue) {
        connectionLocked = true;

        std::cout << "Message: ";
        char* buf = msg.getOutputBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < msg.size(); i++){
            std::cout << (buf[i] + 0) << ":"; //Never any errors
        }

        boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(msg.getOutputBuffer(), msg.size()),boost::bind(&Session::handle_write, shared_from_this(), msg, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

    }
    else {
        //Queue message
        _msgqueue.push_back(msg);
    }

}
void handle_write(NetworkMessage& msg, const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if (error)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << error << endl;
        outputMessage(msg, true); //works, even though it's the same message
    }
    else {
        if(_msgqueue.size() != 0){
            //cout << "Sending queued message #" << _msgqueue.size() << endl;
            outputMessage(_msgqueue.front(), true);
            _msgqueue.pop_front();
        }
        else
            connectionLocked = false;
    }
}
```

This is the code for my send function basically. It works fine, usually. For some reason when I'm sending a lot of messages in a row, this error(System.10014) happens. I tried reading about the error in Winsock, but I really don't understand it(it says something about invalid pointers but I'm pretty sure the message is valid because sending it again works just fine?). And I have little experience with programming and especially with C++ and pointers so I'm having a little trouble.

The loop that generates the messages goes a little like this. I verified that the X and Y are valid, so I'm pretty sure the problem isn't there.

```
map->cursor = map->begin;
while(map->cursor != NULL)
{
    //I'm not sure if pointers like this are supposed to be deleted?
    //I suck when it comes to memory management, and most other things :D
    Tile* tile = map->cursor->tile;
    if(tile){
        NetworkMessage msg;
        msg.AddByte(0x03);
        msg.AddByte(tile->posx);
        msg.AddByte(tile->posy);
        msg.AddByte(1);
        msg.AddByte(2);
        outputMessage(msg);
    }
    else
        break;
    map->cursor = map->cursor->next;

}
```

Also, this might not seem relevant but if I try changing my outputMessage to this:

```
void outputMessage(NetworkMessage& msg)
{
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(msg.getOutputBuffer(), msg.size()),boost::bind(&Session::handle_write, shared_from_this(), msg, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
void handle_write(NetworkMessage& msg, const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if (error)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << error << endl;
    }
}
```

I don't get any errors, but the messages sent are all clones. So the 600 messages all look the same. It seemed weird, so I thought it may be relevant to the problem I'm having now.

Also here's NetworkMessage.h, I also posted it on pastebin you can see in the comments.

```
#ifndef _NETWORK_MESSAGE_H
#define _NETWORK_MESSAGE_H
class NetworkMessage
{
    public:
        enum { header_length = 2 };
        enum { max_body_length = NETWORKMESSAGE_MAXSIZE - header_length};
        NetworkMessage()
        {
            buf_size=0;
            m_ReadPos=header_length;
        }
        void AddByte(char byte_)
        {
            if (!canAdd(1)) return;
            data_[m_ReadPos++] = byte_;
            //data_[m_ReadPos] = '\0';
            buf_size++;
        }
        uint16_t PeekU16(){
            return (data_[1] | uint16_t(data_[0]) << 8);
        }
        uint16_t GetU16(){
            m_ReadPos += 2;
            return (data_[m_ReadPos+1]) | (uint16_t(data_[m_ReadPos]) << 8);
        }

        uint8_t  GetByte(){return data_[m_ReadPos++];}
        char* getBuffer()
        {
            return (char*)&data_[m_ReadPos];
        }
        char* getOutputBuffer()
        {
            writeMessageLength();
            return (char*)&data_[0];
        }

        void setMessageLength(uint16_t v)
        {
            buf_size=v;
        }
        void writeMessageLength()
        {
            *(uint8_t*)(data_) = (buf_size >> 8);
            *(uint8_t*)(data_+1) = buf_size;
        }
        void reset()
        {
            m_ReadPos = 0;
            buf_size = 0;
        }
        uint16_t size(){return buf_size+header_length;}
    protected:
        inline bool canAdd(uint32_t size)
        {
            return (size + m_ReadPos < max_body_length);
        };
    private:
        uint8_t data_[NETWORKMESSAGE_MAXSIZE];
        uint16_t buf_size;
        uint16_t m_ReadPos;
};
#endif //_NETWORK_MESSAGE_H
```

Update: Alright so, came across something weird...

```
function error_func(NetworkMessage& msg){
    cout << &msg << endl; //0x2882e8(not 0x274c0e8)
    send(msg.getOutputBuffer(), msg.size(), error_func, msg); //no error
}
cout << &msg << endl; //0x274c0e8
send(msg.getOutputBuffer(), msg.size(), error_func, msg); //error system.10014
```

Obviously this isn't real code, but you get the idea... I guess this is why re-sending it from error_func works. The problem might be in NetworkMessage after all. I've been messing in all the wrong places all this time :D Still need help though, lol.

Would really appreciate any help, I'm stuck. Thanks for reading if you got this far..

Comment: Can you show the code for `NetworkMessage::getOutputBuffer` and `NetworkMessage::size`?

Comment: Can you post definition of `NetworkMessage`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EABUYxEx I removed some of the "clutter" so it looks a little bit simpler, but that's about it. I copied some of it from another project :D Atleast the names.

Comment: Ok, I have a little update. I tried printing out the memory address of the message when I get an error. It's not the same address as the one I sent. Let me elaborate: Update: I'll edit main post, typing code here doesn't work.

Comment: Fixed it! Not sure exactly why this fixed it though. Would really appreciate an explanation so this wouldn't happen again. Updated first post.

Comment: please don't edit your question if you have solved it. Rollback your edits to their original form and add an answer to your own question. That way it will help future users who find this question and have a similar problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void outputMessage(NetworkMessage& msg, bool forceTrue = false)
{
    if(!connectionLocked || forceTrue) {
        connectionLocked = true;

        std::cout << "Message: ";
        char* buf = msg.getOutputBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < msg.size(); i++){
            std::cout << (buf[i] + 0) << ":"; //Never any errors
        }

        boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(msg.getOutputBuffer(), msg.size()),boost::bind(&Session::handle_write, shared_from_this(), msg, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

    }
    else {
        //Queue message
        _msgqueue.push_back(msg);
    }
}
```

the buffer passed to `async_write` needs to be valid throughout the duration of the operation. The documentation is [very explicit here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html)

> One or more buffers containing the data to be written. Although the
>   buffers object may be copied as necessary, ownership of the underlying
>   memory blocks is retained by the caller, **which must guarantee that
>   they remain valid until the handler is called**.

You've passed a pointer that is no longer valid when the `NetworkMessage` object is destroyed, which I am guessing is before the `async_write` operation completes. The `NetworkMessage` object is copied when passed to your `handle_write()` completion handler.